# SYNC MYSQL database instantly from one Digital ocean server to another

Tags: database, database-mirroring, database-replication

I have a site (data entry site ) on a Digital Ocean server and its database ( MYSQL ) is being updated with new records every second.

I am hosting the public site on another Digital ocean server which is only reading information from the database.

How can I Sync the database tables on public site with data-entry-site database tables. I am looking for one way Sync only. ( data-entry-site --> public site )

Thanks

Comment: Use replication. then chose a moment and switch between DBs. Some instand downtime is imminent, though.

Comment: can you please elaborate "downtime". I need this to be automatic, every minute  or second .

Comment: I thought you are about to switch installations. If not, why don;'t you just connect the second installation to the original database ?

Comment: yes that's an alternate solution, but i wanted to have two seperate databases, because if the public site is down for some reason, i don't want the data entry team to relax by doing nothing. :)

Comment: Then a replication definitely. No downtime.

Comment: is it that perfect ? as soon as a record is added on data entry database it will show up instantly on public site ?

Comment: No, mysql replication is asyncronous by default, and from 5.7+ it can be semisyncronous, but anyway new data won't appear instantly: some lag definitely will take place. How big it will be - this depends on the actual installation. Usually we are speaking about dozens or hundreds of milliseconds. But sometimes this may become hours.